# PHP обход chmod

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Скажите, как можно сменить права на файл, если функция chmod отключена? Возможно есть вариант через создание своей функции?

Comment: Создать другой файл, если при создании получаются нужные права, скопировать данные из старого. удалить старый. переименовать новый

Comment: А как насчёт варианта, если в папке запрещено создавать файлы?

Comment: А тогда вы и права не поменяете. изменение прав файла это такая же запись в каталог, как и создание файла и следовательно и на нее не будет прав

Comment: Вообще без вариантов? Доступны функции eval и umask. Сейчас с ними разбираюсь, толку я так понял от них 0?

Comment: Так если прав записи нет, то их нет, без вариантов. даже если бы chmod был доступен вы бы все равно ничего не сделали. если конечно вы не сможете поменять права на каталог в котором это находится

Comment: Права на запись доступно в основной каталог, может можно быстро перенести содержимое всего каталога в новый каталог, чтобы у всех файлов были права на запись?

Comment: можно перенести. только созданием новых файлов и переписыванием содержимого. хотя imho проще мне кажется поменять права на каталог, что бы в него запись была возможна а потом меняйте права на файлы

Comment: В принципе права на изменение прав для папок и файлов у меня есть, просто отключена функция chmod.

Comment: если есть права на изменение прав то и на создание файлов должны быть